# oozie is not allowed to impersonate oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am kinda new with oozie. I installed (with the cdh repo )oozie on my server (I followed the CDH4 documentation [my hadoop is running in cdh4]).

I have update my core-site.xml with the following information:

```
<!-- OOZIE -->
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<!-- -->
```

But when I start a job:

```
sudo -u oozie oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/sqoopList/job.properties -run
```

I get:

```
job: 0000004-130530171203897-oozie-oozi-W
```

But when I look in the oozie webconsole, I can see my job but my job has the status "START_RETRY"
with the following error

```
JA009: User: oozie is not allowed to impersonate oozie
```

and I dont have any logs..... I really dont know what is wrong..

I cant understand why I cannot start a job?
Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you restart the hadoop core services for the change in core-site.xml to take place? Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582126/getting-e0902-exception-occured-user-oozie-is-not-allowed-to-impersonate-ooz

Comment: Hey Anthony I am getting the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: same problem here, would love feedback on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

1. If Oozie server and Hadoop daemons are on different machines and if you are using *oozie* user for running commands: You must create *oozie* user and *oozie* group on hadoop machine. If you have a Hadoop cluster with NameNode running on a seperate machine, create these in NameNode machine. Adding oozie group can be redundant if * wildcard is used (I did not test against this); but you should assign a group to *oozie* user. This way HDFS can collect user's group information.

This is my configuration:

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
<value>oozie</value>
</property>
```

2. After adding oozie user and group, restart the hadoop daemons. When hadoop is back again, it will have group mappings of *oozie* user.

The logic behind these actions is stated in HDFS permissions guide:

> Once a username has been determined as described above, the list of
>   groups is determined by a group mapping service, configured by the
>   hadoop.security.group.mapping property. The default implementation,
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping, will shell out
>   to the Unix bash -c groups command to resolve a list of groups for a
>   user.
>
> For HDFS, the mapping of users to groups is performed on the NameNode.
>   Thus, the host system configuration of the NameNode determines the
>   group mappings for the users.

Following 2 links can give a summary on HDFS permissions.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/authorization-and-authentication-in-hadoop/

Answer (score 0):

I had come across the same problem while using **Apache** Oozie.

Add the following in oozie-site.xml

```
<property>
 <name>oozie.services.ext</name>
 <value>org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService</value >
 <description>
  To add/replace services defined in 'oozie.services' with custom implementations.Class names must be separated   by commas.
 </description>
</property>
```

Then restart oozie.
This should work with Cloudera distribution also.Just give it a try and do let me know.

Answer (score -1):

set below properties in HDFS config using ambari or CLI
 Key=hadoop.proxyuser.hostname.hosts
 value= *

key=hadoop.proxyuser.hostname.groups
 value=*

If you are getting "user hue not defined as proxyuser" in Hue then follow below steps:

Step 1: In Ambari UI click on oozie
Step 2: Click on "configs" to enter config parameters
Step 3: Go to Custom oozie-site and add below 2 properties

key=oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.hue.groups
value= *

key=oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.hue.hosts
value=*

Comment: Format the answer well.

Comment: hostname is not username, hue has nothing to do with the question.