# Error: E0902: Exception occured: [User: Root is not allowed to impersonate root

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to follow the steps given  at   http://www.rohitmenon.com/index.php/apache-oozie-installation/
    Note: I am not using cloudera distibution of hadoop

The above link is similar to http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_QuickStart.html 
 but with more descriptive seems to me 
however while running  the below command as a root user i am getting  exception
       ./bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs

Note: i have two live node shown at dfshealth.jsp . and i have updated the core-site.xml for all  three(including namenode) with property as below

```
  <property>
            <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
            <value>*</value>
     </property>

    <property>
            <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
            <value>*</value>
    </property>
```

i understand this is point where i am making mistake Could someone please guide me

```
Stacktrace
    org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorException: E0902: Exception occured: [User: root is not allowed to impersonate root]
            at 

    org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createFileSystem(HadoopAccessorService.java:430)
                at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieSharelibCLI.run(OozieSharelibCLI.java:144)
                at org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieSharelibCLI.main(OozieSharelibCLI.java:52)
        Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: User: root is not allowed to impersonate root
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1107)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:411)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:276)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:241)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1411)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1429)
                at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
                at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$2.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:422)
                at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService$2.run(HadoopAccessorService.java:420)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
                at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1136)
                at org.apache.oozie.service.HadoopAccessorService.createFileSystem(HadoopAccessorService.java:420)
                ... 2 more
        --------------------------------------
```

Note: [Getting E0902: Exception occured: [User: oozie is not allowed to impersonate oozie]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582126/getting-e0902-exception-occured-user-oozie-is-not-allowed-to-impersonate-ooz)  i have followed this link as well but not able to solve my problem

```
if i change the core-site.xml as below only for NameNode

<property>
        <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.hosts</name>
        <value>[NAMENODE IP]</value>
    </property>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hadoop.groups</name>
    <value>hadoop</value>
</property>
```

I get the exception as
Unauthorized connection for super-user: hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the property files into core-site.xml restart your hadoop and try. Even though if it not works format the namenode and start hadoop it will work.

Comment: How to get reloaded the property at runtime to solve this exception?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these properties in core-site.xml for impersonation in order to solve your whitelist error

```
 <property> 
 <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name> 
 <value>*</value> 
 </property> 

 <property> 
 <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name> 
 <value>*</value> 
 </property>
```

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: What if my user name has a '.'. For example, abc.xyz?

Comment: The * would consider any kindoff user names

Comment: I meant the proxyuser is abc.xyz

Comment: I came across a post saying that it won't support the . in user name. Pls see it here: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Oozie-users/conversations/messages/407

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice in the article below. Hadoop before 1.1.0 doesn't support wildcard so you have to explicitly specified the hosts and the groups

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oozie-user/201212.mbox/%3CCAOcnVr1TZZ5X0Mrb7fFA8JdW6rO6PgoJ9u0=2UYbfXf_o8r=DA@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding those lines in the `core-site.xml`-file

```
hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts
value = *

hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups
value = *
```

and it works perfectly all my databases and tables are shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000
```

try to run this command using sudo.

check for hdfs if this path already exits i.e., `/user/user_name/share/lib`, if it exists remove it using

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/user_name
```

After that run `sudo ./oozied.sh`. oozie will be started. Then check for your `localhost:11000`.