# Oozie invalid user in secure mode

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, oozie

Configured oozie to work with hadoop-2.6.0 and enabled kerberos security.

I didn't get ticket using **kinit** command but when i submit job using below command,

```
oozie job -oozie http://hostname:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

it throws the following exception,

```
Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, User: oozie/hostname@EXAMPLE.COM is not allowed to impersonate Kumar
```

I know how to solve the above error but my question is

**Kumar** is my local account username. As i configured kerberos, it should check my user ticket. But it didn't show me any error like **"No credential found"**

If i get ticket using **kinit** for any other user then also oozie shows the same exception with my local user account name.

Is there anything to configure? I don't understand the concept. I am following [this](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-3-1/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_6_1.html) to configure oozie with kerberos on secured cluster.

Comment: It might be the basic core-site.xml oozie configuration issue refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582126/getting-e0902-exception-occured-user-oozie-is-not-allowed-to-impersonate-ooz

Comment: @KSNidhin Please read my question. I am asking question about kerberos not about impersonate issue, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer in [Oozie Authentication](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Authentication)

`Once authentication is performed successfully the received authentication token is cached in the user home directory in the .oozie-auth-token file with owner-only permissions. Subsequent requests reuse the cached token while valid.`

This is the reason for using invalid user even getting the ticket for any other user using kinit command.

I just resolved as below

`The use of the cache file can be disabled by invoking the oozie CLI with the -Doozie.auth.token.cache false= option`.

Try this.